# Control validation in wpf which is inside a resource style C#

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm using navigation window in wpf which has a style applied on it. Inside that style there are textboxes. I use MVVM pattern and my model implements IDataErrorInfo and returns error for these textboxes. Everything releated to data binding works just fine, but validation highlighting fails. There is no problem with styles, I have set special style for validation error for these textboxes. When I use the same not inside resource, then valdiation works correct.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure your Style is an implicit style so it gets applied to your TextBoxes. If you have an x:Key on your style, then remove it.

Comment: That style definitely applies to my control. Everything works well when the same xaml is not inside a resource, but just inside content template of window.